# Codeigniter gives a URL not foun

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, codeigniter

im trying to do a simple click and go to another page but codeigniter is giving me ''NOT FOUND, The requested URL was not found on this server.''

Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/7.4.20 Server at localhost Port 80

My controller:

```
<?php

class Onekey extends MY_Controller {

   public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();

     $this->load->model('Onekey_model'); 
    }

    public function index(){
       $this->render('onekey', 'Onekey_model');
    }

     public function teste(){
       $this->render('teste', 'Onekey_model');
}
```

HTML

`````
    ````<form method="post" action="teste" class="login_form" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <button>Entrar</button></form>````
`````

Htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>


ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Config file

```
$config['index_page'] = 'onekey';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
```

I have tried to use in the form `action="onekey/teste"` and still nothing

EDIT:

If i do `action="index.php/onekey/teste"` it works, so my problem is the index.php, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe combining the RewriteCond for `system` and `application`? also, I added in another line I use in my CI htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA, L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: didnt work. The only way i can get it to work is by change to ````$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';```` and use ````action="index.php/onekey/teste"````. I want to remove the index.php part